# Can we use range find to search multiple words? split()

Tags: excel, vba, split, find

In my code when user inputs in a prompt box "wifi router" , the code searches for this in a text "DrayTek wifi Vigour 2760 (Ethernet, ADSL2+) router".

In this situation code will not have any output.

Can I make my rng.Find to separate wifi and router, and search through the text, and if it fiinds wifi & router will output ?

In other words: Can rng.Find take "AB", separate these two , and output only if A and B is found (together or separately)? Can I use Split() somehow ?

```
firstWord = InputBox("Enter word for bullet_points", "Keyword BOX")
    secondWord = InputBox("Enter word for item_name", "Keyword BOX")
    thirdWord = InputBox("Enter word for product_description", "Keyword BOX")




    LastRow1 = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If firstWord = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow1, 8).Value = "No INPUT"
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow1, 8).Value = firstWord
    End If


    LastRow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If secondWord = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow2, 9).Value = "No INPUT"
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow2, 9).Value = secondWord
    End If


    LastRow3 = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If thirdWord = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow3, 10).Value = "No INPUT"
    Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow3, 10).Value = thirdWord
    End If



    With ws
        If firstWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("B17:B1017"), firstWord
        If secondWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("C17:C1017"), secondWord
        If thirdWord <> "" Then ReplaceText ws.Range("D17:D1017"), thirdWord
    End With



    Exit Sub

Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description

    End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceText(rng As Range, txt As String)



    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim bCell As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range



    Set aCell = rng.Find(What:=txt, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)


    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        Set rngFound = aCell

        Do
            Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Set rngFound = Union(rngFound, aCell)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If



    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        rngFound.Value = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    End If
```

Comment: Replace the space with a wildcard `*`?

Comment: 1) your first example (find _"wifi"_ in _""DrayTek wifi Vigour 2760 (Ethernet, ADSL2+)""_) doesn't fit with the second one (_"take "AB", separate these two , and output only if B is found"_). 2) `Find()`with `LookAt:=xlPart` should run successfully when searching _"wifi"_ in _"DrayTek wifi Vigour 2760 (Ethernet, ADSL2+)"_

Comment: Sorry, I have edit the post :  "wifi router"

Comment: then BigBen suggestion should do for you

Comment: wildcard works, but only if the text contains AB , if we have BA, it doesn't work

Comment: Are you searching strings of any length or always 2? In broad terms yes split your terms (assuming there is a delimiter) and loop through each.

Comment: Instead of `Find`, try using `Filter`. I suspect you will have more success

Comment: filter would need criterias , but the criteria always changes, it depends on user input

Comment: I can split for example firstWord in  WrdString1st1 = Split(firstWord)(0)
   WrdString1st2 = Split(firstWord)(1)  . Is it posiible to use these 2 in my CODE ?  the condition between them should be AND